# Delete a message from OUTGOING QUEUES in msmq

Tags: wcf, message-queue, msmq, msmq-wcf, msmq-transaction

Is it possible to delete a message from outgoing queues? I don't see any option for deleting. How to delete these messages? I am new to msmq. I am trying to send messages from my computer to some other computer. All my messages are sitting in outgoing queue with the status "LOCKED". Not sure why is it locked and I want to delete all these messages in OUTGOING QUEUE.

Comment: Can't you just purge the queue through the MMC?

Comment: it's possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12609601/336511
it did work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The various possible status values are described in [**Internal Private Queues and Outgoing Queues**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733170.aspx).

Emptying an outgoing queue is discussed in this question: [**How to Purge an MSMQ Outgoing Queue**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807742/how-to-purge-an-msmq-outgoing-queue).

I haven't been keeping up to date with MSMQ but I suspect removing individual messages from an outgoing queue is not possible.  Outgoing queues are part of MSMQ's internal infrastructure and shouldn't be manipulated by non-MSMQ code.

Comment: Thanks for all the details. It helped me in understanding the msmq in detail.